# Does it matter how a date is stored for localization? (time not stored)

Tags: web

I store dates as strings in the following format:

```
YYYY,MM,DD // "1969,12,31"
```

I intend to format that string depending on the user's locale on the frontend. Does it matter what format it's stored in? I imagine it doesn't matter, as long as I know how to parse my string on the frontend. If it matters, I don't care about the time, just the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store according to the user locale you also have to store what locale it is, because the frontend locale can change.

So it's much safer and simpler to store a local-independant date format.

Comment: What does a locale independent date format look like? Since I'm not storing the time, is my string okay? I don't care about the user's locale when storing the date. I only care about showing the date in the correct date format on the frontend.

Comment: Yes, YYYY,MM,DD is locale-independant if the date itself is UTC (or GMT).